# Shortcodes in RSS excerpts

Tags: shortcode, rss, excerpt

I am developing a plugin that uses shortcodes. I wanted to enable users to use shortcodes in excerpts, so I added the line

```
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'do_shortcode');
```

which worked fine.However, in my RSS feed, the excerpt is still a shortcode. I tried all of the following:

```
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'do_shortcode');
add_filter('the_excerpt_rss', 'do_shortcode');
add_filter('the_content_rss', 'do_shortcode');
```

But it does not work still. Can someone point me to the right filter so the excerpt would be processed correctly in the feed as well?

Please note that those are manually edited excerpts, not automatically generated ones.

Comment: `add_filter('the_excerpt_rss', 'do_shortcode');` should work fine because I just tried and it did. I think there is some issue in your shortcode handler function. So please update your question to include that code. If possible please share the link of site where you are testing this plugin to see the `/feed` it in action.

Comment: Well wouldn't you know it, I tried the above code that you had there and it worked. Problem solved, I guess :) No idea why it did not work before.

Comment: @ItsMePN as an answer please. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested following code and it worked just fine for me:

```
function my_name_shortcode( $atts ) {
    return "<h3>PRASAD</h3>";
}
add_shortcode( 'name', 'my_name_shortcode' );

add_filter( "the_excerpt_rss", "do_shortcode" );
```

The result can be seen in below screenshot.

[image]